# How to duplicate certain files in a directory?

Tags: r

To be reproducible :
assume you have 5 (file1,file2,file3,file4,file5)files in one directory with the same extension.I would like to make 4 copies of each so I will have 20 files instead of 5 in that directory.

procedures:

```
      1-Read all files
      2- make 4 copies of file1 and put them in the directory as file1-1,file1-2,.... 
      3- make 4 copies of file2 and put them in the directory as file2-1,file2-2,.... 
      4- do the same for all files
```

to read list of file:

```
smith <- list.files("C:\\New folder (3)", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to do this in R?

Comment: You can't have files by the same name in a single directory; at least not without unraveling the space time continuum. Is it ok if they have the different names than the original files?  See `dir` `file.copy` and `file.rename` as they'll likely be your friends.

Comment: @TylerRinker, he wants them as `file1-1, file1-2`.. and so on.

Comment: @ZadSim Don't worry, it is easy! :-) All you need is `list.files` and `file.copy`. And of course some `lapply` love.

Comment: @Zad Sim that required me moving a scroll bar.  I'm what peop[le call efficient (read between the lines: lazy).  Can I ask how you searched (i.e. what you used to search and what search terms you used?).  If you're newer to R or getting help there are some possibilities to make you more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this ***nested lapply loop*** (I just love `lapply`!) and adjust `n` for how many copies you want...

```
f <- list.files( path = "C:\\New folder (3)" , pattern = "*.envi" , full.names = TRUE )
n <- 5
lapply( seq_len( length(f) ) , function(x) { lapply( seq_len( n ) , function( x ,y ){
    file.copy( f[x] , paste0( sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", f[x] ) , "-" , y , ".txt" ) )
    } , x = x )
} )
```

Kudos to [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Extracting-File-Basename-without-Extension-tp878817p878843.html) for the correct `sub` pattern matching to remove the file extension.

Comment: @GavinSimpson in fairness that comment was in reply to one I since deleted, asking him if the answer solved his *reproducible* problem.